# Find a counterexample of the following problem

Tags: real-analysis

We know that, for any two bounded sequences $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$  and $(y_n)_{n\ge1}$ if at least one of them is convergent then, $$\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}(x_n+y_n)=\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n+\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}y_n$$ But is the converse also true? By "converse" I mean the following claim,

> If $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}(x_n+y_n)=\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n+\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}y_n$ then at least one of the two sequences must converge.

I don't think that it holds in general. But to disprove it I need a counterexample which I can't find.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Take $x_{n}=y_{n}=(-1)^{n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Indeed, $\limsup (x_n+x_n)=\limsup x_n + \limsup x_n$ for any sequence $x_n$.

Answer (score 2):

$1,0,1,0,\cdots$,

$1,0,1,0,\cdots$.

Answer (score 2):

$x_{2n}= 0 ,x_{2n+1}=1$

$y_{2n}=0,y_{2n+1}=-1$

$lim sup(x_n+y_n) =0$ and $limsup(x_n)=1$ and $lim sup (y_n)= 0$